# Rundeck is not generating service.log

Tags: rundeck

One of my colleague is trying to install rundeck on a windows 10 OS. We have both followed the documentation guide on Rundeck's website. I was able to run and install Rundeck as a service but my colleague is stuck on the part where we need to run start_rundeck.bat because his Rundeck is not generating service.log. He can access the Rundeck UI but the logs are still not generating. Anyone knows how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague just needs to follow the instructions carefully.

Let me clarify the first steps focused on redirecting the standard output to the `service.log` file, I recreated the Rundeck installation on my Windows virtual machine:

1. First, check the [minimal requirements](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/system-requirements.html). Rundeck needs OpenJDK 11 as the main dependency to work. You can obtain it from [here](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11), [this](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) implementation also works.
2. Create a new directory where the Rundeck `.war` file must be saved, e.g: `C:\rundeck`.
3. Go to [this](https://www.rundeck.com/community-downloads/3.4.6) page and [download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPXOt.jpg) `.war` file on the directory created in the previous step.
4. Open a new PowerShell terminal and set the Rundeck base directory: `set RDECK_BASE=C:\rundeck`.
5. Launch Rundeck for the first time to generate all files: `java -jar rundeck-3.4.6-20211110.war` (inside the directory created in the second step), wait until the `Grails application running at http://localhost:4440` message appear, then stop the instance with `ctrl + c` key combination.
6. With any text editor, create a new file at `C:\rundeck\` path called `start_rundeck.bat` with the following content:

```
set CURDIR=%~dp0
call %CURDIR%etc\profile.bat
java %RDECK_CLI_OPTS% %RDECK_SSL_OPTS% -jar rundeck-3.4.6-20211110.war --skipinstall -d  >> %CURDIR%\var\logs\service.log  2>&1
```

And [save it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtAhC.jpg).

7. Go to the PowerShell terminal and just run the `start_rundeck.bat` file with `.\start_rundeck.bat`.
8. Now check the `C:\rundeck\var\logs\service.log` [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jxJS.jpg).

At this point, it's possible to [continue](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/windows.html#run-rundeck-as-a-service) with the next steps: Configure Rundeck as a service using the `nssm.exe` program.